# Get information from an HTML tag and pass it to PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

So here is the thing. I need to to call a php page from a link (`<a href='name.php'>`) to access my database and print information from those specific links. I think the code is more clear than my question:

```
   <?php

     session_start(); //start session to capture usrName from processLogin.php
     $usrName=$_SESSION['UsrName'];
     $query = "select est_name from students where usrName=".$usrName.";
     $result = $db->query($query);

       while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array(($result)))
                   {

                       echo "<a href="showProfile.php">".$row['est_name']."</a>";
                    //I need to click here and show information that is in the database
                    //for that specific student
                   }
   ?>
```

My question is: Is there a way to name that specific link so I can use it to get the information i want from that specific student?

Comment: Yes, add an id to the link. i.e. `href="showProfile.php?id=foo` where the value is related to the student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the link tag to provide the ID in the query parameters.

```
echo "<a href=\"showProfile.php?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['est_name']}</a>";
// Link will look like <a href="showProfile.php?id=123">Some Name</a>
```

Then you can access this in the `showProfile.php` script by using `$_GET`

```
$student_id = $_GET['id'];
// $student_id will be 123
```

Comment: thank you man... i knew in some way it was possible to do this ... but dont know the exact syntax before. I think this is what i need.

Comment: Hey man and you think is possible to do the same with a submit button so i can submit data in that same way. How can i Identify each submit button created by the while loop?.How I pass that id value with a submit button?

Comment: @CaRlOsGd This really is too in depth for an answer in the comments. However, a true "submit" button would submit all the form values. You can Google this or post a new question (if linked I'll try and grab it) but you can use your flavor of JavaScript to handle the click event on each button, stop it from submitting the form, and based on button ID perform your action. You can also look into styling text _like_ a button, and CSS frameworks like Bootstrap or Semantic UI (my preferred) offer classes for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple way would be to pass it in via a GET parameter (if you are just reading data).  And then use PHP's global $_GET variable to retrieve that value.  The url would be something like this:

```
http://......./myphppage.php?userID=1234
```

And you could access it like this:

```
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
```

**BUT.....**

The way your code is written leaves you open to a SQL injection attack.  Take a look at prepared statements and parameterized queries to protect yourself from them.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.   First of all, I need to point out you have a syntax error in your query.  It should be:

```
$query = "select est_name from students where usrName='.$usrName.'";
```

As for passing the the student info from the link, you would do this (also correcting some problematic syntax with double and single quotes):

```
echo '<a href="showProfile.php?usrName='.$userName=.'">'.$row['est_name']."</a>";
```

Edit:

It's probably a better idea to pass the userid in the session variable.  That way if they are logged in, you don't need to pass the variable in the URL and you can just get the userid from the session, much the way you got `$userName`.   This is considerably safer.

Comment: i know this have some sintax errors. Of course this is not my origanal code. I just wrote that as an example of what i need to do...But thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this ;
1, On log in, you can use that link as the action of you form, when the user submits the form , you catch the name using the post global $_POST['field name ']variable .
2. Or use the get method in you form so that the name is passed in the URL and use the get global variable $_GET['parameter name'] and reuse it to query your database